# Dynamic Programming Implementation- Maximal Square 0's and 1's variant

Tags: algorithm, matrix, dynamic-programming

Given a matrix of 0's and 1's. Find a maximal square where the corner position in a square can either be a zero or one but all other positions must have one. Return the left upper position and right lower position of the maximal square

Given a matrix:

```
0 0 0 1 0 0
0 1 1 1 1 1
1 0 0 1 0 0
1 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
```

The answer must return ((0, 2), (2, 4)) -> ((i, j), (i, j))

Comment: I simplified my answer to simply O(n).

Comment: I understood til finding the maximal square with all 1's but can you explain how can we extend this algorithm in finding a maximal square where the corner position in a square can either be a zero or one but all other positions must have one

Comment: I added more clarification to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

One way that's `O(num elements in the matrix)` is to use the canonical dynamic program (`dp(i,j) = 1 + min(dp(i-1,j), dp(i,j-1), dp(i-1,j-1))` to find all largest squares containing *all* `1`s. Then an extention that uses the new special rule would consist of 4 such squares, overlapping.

For example, if a largest square's bottom-right corner indicates it's a 3×3, to extend it to 5×5 with the special rule, we would have to confirm that its neighbours; left, right, above and below; also indicate they are bottom-right of a 3×3.

Cell `A` below in the canonical dynamic program will have the value 3, indicating 3x3. If `W`, `E`, `N` and `S` also have 3 or 4, we can count the square with bottom-right next after `A` as 5x5 according to the special rule.

However, `A` could also have the value 4 if the top-left were 1, for example, so the logic would need to consider both the scenario where the largest with all 1s is 1 cell shorter than the answer or the scenario where it's 2 cells shorter than the answer. Left for the reader.

```
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0
0  1  1  1  1  1  0  0
0  1  1  1  1N 1  0  0
0  1  1  1W 1A 1E 0  0
0  0  1  1  1S 0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

Comment: I understood the above explanation.
Can you please explain the below part? When you mean top-left were 1, Is it top Left of A is 1? Can you please elaborate it?
However, A could also have the value 4 if the top-left were 1, for example, so the logic would need to consider both the scenario where the largest with all 1s is 1 cell shorter than the answer or the scenario where it's 2 cells shorter than the answer. Left for the reader.

Comment: @Sach sorry, by "top-left," I meant cell (1,1), the cell that's currently 0 but if we changed it to 1, it could make A the bottom-right of a 4×4 all 1s square.